# Is there a way to sort backups listed in Rom Manager?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, rom-manager

One of the older versions of Rom Manager I used to use did this, but more recently my backups, as listed by Rom Manager, seem to be listed in whichever order they please. This is quite annoying when I keep a lot of backups and they are all named only by ROM, date, and time.

Is there a way to sort them alphabetically and/or by date?

I'm using a Motorola Droid X (shadow). I switch between MIUI (Feb. 2012, GB 2.3.7) and CM9 (July 2012, ICS 4.0.4). Using the latest Rom Manager from the Play store, which appears to be 5.5.2.8.

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: Nevermind. Turns out the Rom Manager installation on CM9 wasn't actually up to date, and apparently my backups were not all named consistently. It seems that Rom Manager uses the format:

`YYYY-MM-DD-HH.nn.ss`

while CWM Recovery uses the format:

`YYYY-MM-DD.HH.nn.ss`

which is why they didn't seem to sort correctly. Updating and making the names consistent solved the issue.

Comment: If you found the answer for your question, please post is as an answer and accept it so that Tue others can use it as a help source in the future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Nevermind. Turns out the Rom Manager installation on CM9 wasn't actually up to date, and apparently my backups were not all named consistently. It seems that Rom Manager uses the format:

YYYY-MM-DD-HH.nn.ss

while CWM Recovery uses the format:

YYYY-MM-DD.HH.nn.ss

which is why they didn't seem to sort correctly. Updating and making the names consistent solved the issue.